# Overlaying Bitmaps using ARGB and Graphics C#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, alpha-transparency

i am trying to overlay two bitmaps

I have 2 ARGB (Format32bppArgb) bitmaps.  Bitmap "A" has some regions of pixels with an apha channel value of 0 (transparent) and others with a value ranging from ~200 - 255.  Bitmap "B" pixels all have alpha channels of value 255.  I am drawing each of them to a Graphic like so...

```
Bitmap OverlayBitmaps(Bitmap underlying, Bitmap overlaying)
    {
        Bitmap finalImage = new Bitmap(underlying.Width, underlying.Height,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(finalImage))//get the underlying graphics object from the image.
            {

            graphics.DrawImage(underlying, new Rectangle(0,0, underlying.Width, underlying.Height));
            graphics.DrawImage(overlaying, new Rectangle(0, 0, overlaying.Width, overlaying.Height));

            finalImage.Save("C:\\test.bmp");
            return finalImage;
        }
    }
```

Both "A" and "B" are the same format same height same width but when i save the image, it looks as though only "B" was drawn.

**Is this because "B" alpha channel value dominates?**

i thought that by drawing "B" first, then "A", "A"s pixels with alpha channels value ~200-250 would be on top of "B"

I must be missing something...Any suggestions?

Comment: save the file as a PNG and see what it looks like - specify the image format

Comment: SOLVED: Draw Bitmap A before B.  Sorry for the dumb question :)

Answer (score 1):

Drawing Bitmap "A" before "B" seems to be the answer.  so simple and i tried so much before this little change.  Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Not sure why question and answer downvoted. Anyway +1